# Extract data from Array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to extract hierarchical the details for each "Marca" from xml. My array should take all the 'Diametru', all the 'Latime', all the 'PCD', etc for each "Marca". I was trying to do like that but still something wrong.... I would apreciate any advice:

```
<?php
$jante = "http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/feeds/alcarRO_wheels_feed.xml";

$xml=simplexml_load_file($jante);
$arrayName =array();

foreach($xml->Produs as $child)
{
    $arrayName['marca'] = (string)$child->Marca;

    if ($arrayName['marca'] == (string)$child->Marca){
            $arrayName['marca']['diametru'][] = (int)$child->Diametru;
            $arrayName['marca']['latime'][] = (int)$child->Latime;
            $arrayName['marca']['pcd'][] = (int)$child->PCD;
            $arrayName['marca']['pcd1'][] = (int)$child->PCD1;
            $arrayName['marca']['et'][] = (int)$child->ET;
            $arrayName['marca']['cb'][] = (int)$child->CB;
    }   
}

$arrayName['marca'] = array_unique($arrayName['marca']);
$arrayName['marca']['diametru'] = array_unique($arrayName['diametru']);
$arrayName['marca']['latime'] = array_unique($arrayName['latime']); 
$arrayName['marca']['pcd'] = array_unique($arrayName['pcd']);
$arrayName['marca']['pcd1'] = array_unique($arrayName['pcd1']);
$arrayName['marca']['et'] = array_unique($arrayName['et']);
$arrayName['marca']['cb'] = array_unique($arrayName['cb']);


print_r($arrayName);
```

A Sample of my desired output structure:

```
Array
(
[marca] => AEZ
    (
        [diametru] => Array
            (
                [0] => 15
                [2] => 16
                [3] => 17
                ........
            )

        [latime] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6
                [3] => 7
                [31] => 5
                ........
            )

        [pcd] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 5
                [67] => 6
                ........
            )

        [pcd1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 100
                [1] => 112
                [2] => 114
                ........
            )

        [et] => Array
            (
                [0] => 40
                [1] => 47
                [2] => 48
                ........
            )

        [cb] => Array
            (
                [0] => 60
                [1] => 57
                [2] => 72
                ........
            )

    )

[marca] => ALCAR STAHLRAD
    (
        [diametru] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [2] => 22
                [3] => 2
                ........
            )

        [latime] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6
                [3] => 3
                [31] => 5
                ........
            )

        [pcd] => Array
            (
                [0] => 7
                [1] => 5
                [67] => 8
                ........
            )

        [pcd1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 90
                [1] => 11
                [2] => 114
                ........
            )

        [et] => Array
            (
                [0] => 40
                [1] => 48
                [2] => 48
                ........
            )

        [cb] => Array
            (
                [0] => 7
                [1] => 57
                [2] => 72
                ........
            )   

    )

[marca] => ......
    ....................
```

Comment: _"but still something wrong"_ means what _exactly_? What is the current output?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Why are you doing `if ($arrayName['marca'] == (string)$child->Marca)`. You're literally setting `$arrayName['marca']` to `(string)$child->Marca` on the previous line, so why would that even do anything. You should post your expected output from `print_r($arrayName)`.

Comment: The output is there: http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/mark.php

Comment: "Marca" it appears not only one time, and I try to set a condition for Marca AEZ to take all the details, then go to other "Marca" and collect again all the details.

Comment: I was triyng also like that:

Comment: foreach($xml->Produs as $child)
 {  
  $arrayName['marca'] = (string)$child->Marca;
  $arrayName['diametru'][] = (int)$child->Diametru;
  $arrayName['latime'][] = (int)$child->Latime;
  $arrayName['pcd'][] = (int)$child->PCD;
  $arrayName['pcd1'][] = (int)$child->PCD1;
  $arrayName['et'][] = (int)$child->ET;
  $arrayName['cb'][] = (int)$child->CB;
  
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<?php
$jante = "http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/feeds/alcarRO_wheels_feed.xml";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($jante);
$items = [];  // prepare main array

foreach($xml->Produs as $child)
{
   // collect details of this current item:
   $item = [];
   $item['diametru'] = (int)$child->Diametru;
   $item['latime'] = (int)$child->Latime;
   $item['pcd'] = (int)$child->PCD;
   $item['pcd1'] = (int)$child->PCD1;
   $item['et'] = (int)$child->ET;
   $item['cb'] = (int)$child->CB;

   // add this item to the main array, structured by 'marca'
   $marca = (string)$child->Marca;
   $items[$marca][] = $item;   
}

var_dump($items);
```

**EDIT**:
This is a new version to get your desired structure:

```
foreach($xml->Produs as $child)
{
   $marca = (string)$child->Marca;
   if(!isset($items[$marca])) {
       $items[$marca] = [];
   }
   $items[$marca]['diametru'][] = (int)$child->Diametru;
   $items[$marca]['latime'][] = (int)$child->Latime;
   $items[$marca]['pcd'][] = (int)$child->PCD;
   $items[$marca]['pcd1'][] = (int)$child->PCD1;
   $items[$marca]['et'][] = (int)$child->ET;
   $items[$marca]['cb'][] = (int)$child->CB;
}

// EDIT 2:
// to make the entries unique you could loop through marcas
foreach($items as $marca => $item) {
   $items[$marca]['diametru'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['diametru']);
   $items[$marca]['latime'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['latime']);
   // repeat for other fields...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Now the output is better but still not an yerarchical array: http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/mark.php; I would like to use that code for a filter: when somebody will choose the "Marca" for example Samsung, they should see (Diametru, Latime, PCD, etc ) values for Samsung.

Comment: then please add a sample of the desired structure _to your question_, as @FrankerZ already asked for. Til now we can only guess.

Comment: @FrankerZ 

Marca
 Diametru: 2,6,8
 Latime: 4,6,7
 PCD: 2,3,6
 PCD1: 5,8,9
 ET: 7,9,5
 CB: 0,7,8

Marca2
 Diametru: 0,1,6
 Latime: 4,6,7
 PCD: 2,3,6
 PCD1: 5,8,9
 ET: 7,9,4
 CB: 0,7,8
 so on...
 
 I will collect all the "Diametru", "Latime", "PCD", etc details for every Marca, Marca2, Marca3, etc.
 In xml are structured by products, but I would like to create for my filter a "Marca" search to not wait 5-8 seconds untill the xml is loading.

Comment: _"please add a sample of the desired structure to your question"_

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Could you tell me where to put "array_unique" because I can see many similar values?

Comment: I'd do a loop through the `$marca`s and do it then for 'diametru',.. Other poss is to check already in first loop if the value already exists. Would need a benchmark which one is faster (depends on the diversity of the dataset)

Comment: I was trying to do like that but it doesn't work: foreach($xml->Produs as $child)
{
   $marca = (string)$child->Marca;
   if(!isset($items[$marca])) {
       $items[$marca] = [];
   }
   array_unique($items[$marca]['diametru'][]) = (int)$child->Diametru;

Comment: array_unique would be the option in a second loop _afterwards_.

Comment: I don't know if I understand where to put "array_unique", becouse what is below it shows a PHP Fatal error:
`foreach($xml->Produs as $child)
{
   $marca = (string)$child->Marca;
   if(!isset($items[$marca])) {
       array_unique($items[$marca]) = [];
   }
   $items[$marca]['diametru'][] = (int)$child->Diametru; `

Comment: I was doing like that, outside of the foreach, but still doesn't work: `
$items[$marca] = array_unique($items[$marca]);
$items[$marca]['diametru'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['diametru']);
$items[$marca]['latime'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['latime']); 
$items[$marca]['pcd'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['pcd']);
$items[$marca]['pcd1'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['pcd1']);
$items[$marca]['et'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['et']);
$items[$marca]['cb'] = array_unique($items[$marca]['cb']);
`

Comment: you can see yourself that code in comments is not really readable.. I'll do an edit of my answer.